# TypeScript complains about unnecessary assertion

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am using TypeScript 4.6.4 and given is the following function:

```js
function foo(element: HTMLInputElement): void {
    const inputElement: HTMLInputElement = element.firstChild as HTMLInputElement;
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [...]
}
```

The error says:

> This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion

The property `firstChild` is of type `ChildNode`, can anyone help me understand why a cast to `HTMLInputElement` is unnecessary here? If I remove it, it complains that `ChildNode` cannnot be assigned to `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: ESLint complains, not TypeScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) that is complaining not the Typescript compiler. If you try to run your code [In the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBTANhgthsKALkQAkAVAWQBkBJMABxCgFEd9CBKEgNzhgAmiAN4BYAFCIpiCAgDOURDEbM2eAooC8ibOsIA6YDABOCgMIALGFiEBDOWSp0VrdhokBfIA), you'll see that it compiles without error.

The error is raised by `typescript-eslint` because it reads `const inputElement: HTMLInputElement` which indicates that `inputElement` is of type `HTMLInputElement`. Therefore it is correct in saying that asserting `as HTMLInputElement` doesn't change the type of `inputElement`, which is already `HTMLInpuElement`

However you're also correct that `const inputElement: HTMLInputElement = element.firstChild` will raise a compiler error as `firstChild` is indeed of type `ChildNode`.

What you can do to get rid of the warning is `const inputElement = element.firstChild as HTMLInputElement`. This will compile correctly and get read of the redondant typing. `inputElement` will be of type `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Using `const inputElement = element.firstChild as HTMLInputElement` also complains about the cast with the same error message

Comment: Ah, that's odd, I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error using the code I provided. It may be dependent on the `tsconfig` or eslint config you're using. If you provide them I can try to investigate further !

Comment: Hey @araelath, thanks so much! But I believe it's my responsibility to deliver an MVCE. Let me try out a few things and I will post an update. Thanks again!

Comment: The issues were two conflicting `.eslintrc.json`. I set one as `"root":true` which fixed the error.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever find a solution?